# how do we use design patterns in javascript and pass those objects to the server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, design-patterns

The Gang of Four javascript design patterns have a handful of patterns to use. I understand that the patterns are great and can be used at the client side. But how do I pass these objects to the server side with a Asp.net web forms application.

I mean if I would like to pass the javascript object to server side then how do I do it.

I know that i can use ajax calls to methods and pass the objects via jquery.

I would like to know if there is any other way that I could pass the javascript objects to the server side.

I also know that there are hidden fields to pass to server side.

My question is that Is it sensible to use javascript design patterns with asp.net web forms application?

Comment: With .NET, I'd use WCF which support JSON web methods.

Comment: What about a web forms application? How would I do it?

Comment: Same way.  I'd use WCF.

Comment: LOL @ people saying "use WCF".  this question is too vague and open ended to give reasonable guidance around.  @sly_Chandan, how about you tell us what design pattern your looking at and which responsibility would be client-side vs. server-side?

Comment: Ok....How do I pass a javascript object to an aspx page?

Comment: You don't. You can pass the state of the javascript object (methods as mentioned above) to the server where it will create a native runtime object and reinflate it with the state transported over the wire.

Comment: Trust me.  Go dig up a basic WCF tutorial that covers creating JavaScript proxies.  That's the approach you want to use for .NET.